# iPhone iOS how to export text from UITextView to a text file for cross-platform editing? (Mac, PC, iPhone, etc)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, export, uitextview

I would like to let my app's users export text that they entered into a UITextView. I'm thinking of doing it like this:

```
NSString* string = @"This is the user's text";
[string writeToFile:@"string.txt" atomically:YES];
//then get the file and attach it to email
```

Ideally the user would be able to export UITextView's contents over to dropbox, then edit the file on any computer and still be able to edit it in a UITextView, seeing all the changes from other computers.

**Is there anything that I need to know about saving text so it would appear the same on PC, mac, iPhone, etc? Is there some encoding I need to specify?**

Comment: what problm you are facing or what you 'r expecting will be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` and specify `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.  Reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/writeToFile%3aatomically%3aencoding%3aerror%3a).

Other than encoding, the only thing that could vary is line endings (typically CR for old Mac OS, LF for Mac OS X and other Unix/Linuxes, and CR+LF for Windows).  However, any reasonable text editor should handle any of those with no problem, so you probably don't need to worry about it.